# Can I upgrade Pentium 2117u with Core i3 3110m on my Asus x552cl laptop?

Tags: intel-core-i3

Can I upgrade [Pentium 2117u](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Pentium_Dual-Core_Mobile/2117U.html) with [Core i3 3110m](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_i3_Mobile/i3-3110M_%28BGA%29.html) on my Asus x552cl laptop?

Comment: The thermal power design is likely to be an issue, as the i3 requires twice as much cooling.

Comment: These are solder CPUs...

Comment: thanks for answer... and wht about TDP, 2117u taking 17 watt and 3110m 35 watt?

Comment: @sandeep - What about it?  The 3110 requires 35W to work which is 17W more than you motherboard is capable of providing.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, as these processors use a [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) connection which means they are soldered directly to the circuit boards. Even if you could safely remove the old processor, and correctly solder on the other, the thermal design could lead to issues with overheating.

Comment: 'grats on 2k rep